# How to access data passed from dyamic route from express.js to react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, express-router

Here is my backend route, i'm getting a file name as parameter from URL and accessing the file. how do I access the data passed from this route into my frontend react.js??

```
router.route("/list/:filename").get((req, res) => {
    fs.readFile("./api/assignment_data/" + req.params.filename + ".json", function read(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        const content = data;
        foundFile => res.json(foundFile)
        console.log("sent")
    })
})
```

In my frontend I am doing something like this,

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/list/:filename").then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                console.log("all ok")
                return res.json()
            }
        }).then(jsonRes => setMetrics(jsonRes))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing everything right as long as you are sending correct file name which in react you have marked as `:filename`(like data.json) if you are doing that it should work, I just dont understand this line  `foundFile => res.json(foundFile)` because you are not sending any file in return maybe you can try replacing that line with `res.status(200).json({data});` this should work

Comment: i did this res.status(200).send(data) and it is working but don't know why the useEffect is bein called infinitely..it just doesn't stop..there isn;t a problem but debug console.log keeps printing infinitely..did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: brother i think the problem is here...the fetch in react code doesn't know what is that :filename and hence looks for route ""/list/:filename"" taking filename as a route only rather than a variable that changes... how do I tell react to look for names that are passed?

Comment: I am hoping that he posted the right file name like `user.json` not in actual `:filename`

Answer (score 0):

You are using useeffect wrong this way it will infinitely run rerendering your application everytime there is any change in DOM, so do this

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/list/:filename").then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                console.log("all ok")
                return res.json()
            }
        }).then(jsonRes => setMetrics(jsonRes))
    },[])
```

this way it'll only run once

Comment: It still shows Proxy error: Could not proxy request /lists/:filename from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

Comment: maybe because you are sending request to react server at localhost:3000 try sending it to your express server wherever its hosted(for ex: localhost:5000 or localhost:8080)

Comment: ya it's working on express server but I want the data in frontend

Comment: you must be, check network tab on your browser or just `console.log(res.json())` also check for `res.ok===true`